# Definition of a left coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is something that I do not understand about the definition of a left coset.

> Let $\,G\,$ be a group and $\,H\,$ be a subgroup of $\,G\,$. Then the subset $\,aH=\{ah |h \in H\}\subseteq G\,$ is the left coset of $\,H\,$ containing $\,a.$

What is "$\,a\,$" in this definition? What does it represent? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "$a$" in the definition is any element of $G$: .

So the left coset $\,aH\subseteq G\,$ is the set of all elements in the left coset $aH$, which for a given $\,a \in G\,$ and every element $h_i \in H$, is the set of all $ah_i$.

E.g. Take a small subgroup of $S_3$ : $\;H = \langle (12)\rangle  = \{id, (12)\} \leq S_3.\,$ There are three left (respectively right) cosets of $\,H$ in $\,S_3$. One coset is $\,H\,$ itself. The other cosets are $\,(13)H = (123)H\,$ and $\,(23)H = (132)H$.

You'll see that for any subgroup $\,H \leq G$, every element of $\,G\,$ will belong to *one and only one left (respectively right) coset* of $\,H\,$ in $\,G.\,$  And the *union* of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$ (respectively the union of all right cosets of $H$ in $G$) ***is*** $G$. That is, the left (respectively right) cosets of $H$ in $G$ ***partition*** $G$.

You'll can find a nice definition of "coset" and some examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset), as well.

Comment: amWhy can we say that the union of all left (and also right) cosets of H gives us the group G?

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear now

Comment: Nice Amy. I can stay a bit

Comment: @amWhy: ok - so close to a 10-star! :-) +1 (nice description!)

Answer (score 3):

$a$ can be any element of $G$. For example, let's take the symmetries of the square, $D_4$, and a subgroup of it: $H = \{e, r_1, r_2, r_3\}$. We'll pick $f_v$ for our $g$. $gH = \{ gh : h \in H\} = \{ f_ve, f_vr_1, f_vr_2, f_vr_3 \} = \{ f_v, f_d, f_h, f_c \}$. $f_v$ turns the group of rotations into a set of flips (which is *not* a group).

Comment: Careful. $\bf Z$ is not a group under multiplication. The ultimate moral here is that given a set $X$ and any binary operation $\cdot$ on it, for two subsets $A,B\subseteq X$ we can define $AB=\{a\cdot b:a\in A,b\in B\}$, and in particular for $a\in X$ we can define $aB=\{ab:b\in B\}$ and $Ba=\{ba:b\in B\}$.

Comment: Shoot. I'll go fix that.